# How do i POST to local host with requests library?

Tags: python, post

Im trying to make a post to the following url (http://localhost:1880/notifData) using python in a rpi. For this purpose im using bottle with no problems:

```
from bottle import get, post, run, request

@post('/notifData')
def notifData():
    print(request.body.getvalue())

run(host='localhost', port=1880, debug=True)
```

But when I try to use the requests library im getting a `[Errno 111] Conection refused` error:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://localhost:1880/notifData/')
print(r.text)
```

Can someone explain why its not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You understand that `bottle` is web framework and the first snippet is the web application that has to be running when you post the request from second snippet, right? Also it is good to post some data, so that that there is something to print when server responds.

Comment: Exactly, im running a web application on the following url: http://127.0.0.1:1880/notifData. When i make a HTTP POST request, the data of interest comes in the HTTP body respose, but unfortunatelly im still getting the error described earlier.

Comment: OK, because it was not 100% clear from your question (at least to me). Your code worked for me, although I added some `data` in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Requests raise a *connection error* when there is an event of a network-related issue such as DNS failure or connection refusal. Looking at your code and the error, I would suggest:

1. Making sure that the port (1880) is available for new connections,
2. Disabling proxy on localhost:

   `import os`
   `os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'`
   before sending the post request,
3. Use *'127.0.0.1'* instead of *'localhost'* to send the post request.

Comment: Still getting the same error: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=1880): Max retries exceeded with url: /notifData/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x75d786f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Answer (score 0):

1. Your post method handling function notifData is missing a `return` statement.

> 

```
from bottle import get, post, run, request  

@post('/notifData')
def notifData():
     reqBody = request.body.getvalue()
     print(reqBody)
     return reqBody
 
run(host='localhost', port=1880, debug=True)
```

2. The URL path in the client code making call is incorrect. Remove the extra `/` at the end.

> `r = requests.post('http://localhost:1880/notifData')`